# check-signature tool fails with message: resource envelope is obsolete (custom omit rules)

Tags: macos, signed, osx-gatekeeper, pkg-file

Tried to check Gatekeeper Conformance using check-signature tool as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG4) running the following command:

```
./check-signature ~/Desktop/folder/test.pkg
```

and got the following output:

```
(c) 2014 Apple Inc.  All rights reserved.
/Users/username/Desktop/folder/test.pkg: Warning: bundle installers are deprecated,    please use regular installer packages.
/Users/username/Desktop/folder/test.pkg.pkg: resource envelope is obsolete (custom omit rules)
```

Can somebody help me to understand what the above output means?

Comment: Reboot your mac, do a full clean and rebuild. It fixes the issue after upgrading

Answer (score 2):

Your "resource envelope is obsolete" error means you have a "version 1" signature and are checking it on a machine running OS X 10.9.5 or newer.

Starting with OS X 10.9.5 and continuing with 10.10 and later, Apple has changed the way code signing works.  Apple Tech Note 2206, available here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html

explains the new code signing requirements.  In general, you will need to sign your code and package on a machine running 10.9 or later in order to generate a "version 2" signature.  Note: you cannot simply copy the 'codesign' or 'productsign' from a 10.9 machine to a machine running 10.8 or lower.  These tools rely on other components of the OS to do their work, so you actually need to generate your signature on a machine running 10.9 or higher.

Comment: That can't be the only reason for a "resource envelope is obsolete (custom omit rules)" error, these days at least.  I just got it as output from `codesign -R='anchor apple generic' --deep-verify -v Install\ macOS\ Monterey\ \(v.17.0.07\).app`.  I'll be trashing it and downloading again, since it would install macOS 12.0.1, and I want macOS 12.1.  (I had downloaded it weeks ago, directly from Apple, when it was current.) Maybe it is the only reason when it comes with the previous error too, but it seems Apple is using it for other things too now.